# Как правильно пишется в данном предложении "не" с прилагательным?

Tags: орфография, частица-не

"День не()скучного здоровья".

Answer (score 1):

Это только организаторы и могут сказать, как оно пишется в данном случае.
В принципе можно представить, что имелось в виду и отрицание "скучного", даже несмотря на отсутствие противоставления или наречия степени или образа дейсвтвия.  Скажем, накануе был просто день здороья. А этот вообше никакой. Не нескучный, но и точно не скучный. Как-то так.
Но если предположить, что у организатов мозги всё-таки не совсем расплавилиьс, то, конечно, слитно. В занчении "веселого здоровья".

Answer (score 0):

Странное у Вас какое-то предложение. Но раз в нем нет противопоставления с союзом "а" и слов "вовсе", "ничуть" и др., то не пишется слитно.

Comment: Спасибо. Это к счастью не моё странное предложение, такое название придумали организаторы "недели здоровья". А я засомневалась в грамотности этого словосочетания. Спасибо ещё раз